# How do I display a whole number in Firebird?

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird-3.0

I am calculating an average in Firebird, and need only the whole number as a result. By using the "TRUNC" function I can get the number to display "99.000", but all I want is "99". I cannot find anything in the Firebird 3.0 language reference guide that describes how to get such a number to display. Is this even possible in Firebird?

Comment: Firebird does not display anything. Firebird is a server, it throws binary data in and out. It is your **database client application** which decides how to turn binary data into human readable text. There are some hacks to influence client apps behavior by altering binary formats, but they have limited effect and no warranties

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`cast()`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-scalarfuncs-cast):

```
select cast(val as int)
```

Alternatively, you can use [`floor()`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-scalarfuncs-floor):

```
select floor(val)
```